# How to generate multiple QR codes?

Tags: python, qr-code

I have defined 2 functions and in my main program i am calling these functions to produce multiple encode qr codes. I have correctly generated my_string (the url) which encodes the data for the qr code but i am struggling to call the 'generate_qr' function with the my_string(url data) to generate multiple qr codes. Note i have taken out the url that i am actually using and have just referred to it as url in the def 1 and my_string in my main program.

## Definition 1

```
def generate_string(id):
    Base_string ='url 'End_string ='end_of_url'
    Final_string = Base_string + id + End_string
    return Final_string
```

## Definition 2

```
def generate_qr(Final_string):
    qr=qrcode.QRCode(version=1,box_size=5,border=5,)
    data= Final_string
    qr.add_data(data)
    qr.make(fit=True)
    img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")
    return img
```

## Main

## Dataframe with IDs

```
data=[['x1',"'50080541'"],['x2',"'50079059'"],['x3',"'50084926'"],['x4',"'50096605'"],['x5',"'50100828'"]]
tech=df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['names','id'])

for index,row in tech.iterrows():
    my_string= generate_string (row['id'])
    print(my_string)
    final_qr= generate_qr(my_string)
    print(final_qr)
```

Comment: you have wrong indentations. Edit question and format it correctly. When you put  code then you can use button `{}` to display it correctly.

Comment: Apologies, i think the indentations should be correct now? I dont understand the second part of your comment. Do i need to format a string using the f { } ?

Comment: When you edit question you have toolbar with buttons to set bold text, set italic text, insert image, etc. There is also button `{}` to inform Stackoverflow which part of your question is a code and SO will display it as code - using colors. It has nothing to do with string formating in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't the well formatted, however it seems like you're trying to pass the function `generate_string` to the `generate_qr` function, instead of `my_string`, which is the **output** of the `generate_string` function.

Try

```
final_qr = generate_qr(my_string)
```

Comment: That was my original code until i fiddle with it, i have changed it back to pass my_string into the generate_qr function.The output i get is the URL which is correct but my qr code comes out like this:                
 <qrcode.image.pil.PilImage object at 0x0000017C814A9234560>  do you have any suggestions on what im doign incorrectly. I need to get the image.

Comment: You do have the image - it's saved in the `img` object, and you're just printing that image object's string respresentation to the screen (which just tells you it's an object and its memory location). Looking at the [qrcode source code](https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode/blob/master/qrcode/image/pil.py) for the image class - you can use `save` e.g. `img.save('path/to/save/img.bmp')` and view the image via your OS's image viewer.